# C++ OpenMP post order traversal wrong print order

Tags: c++, multithreading, tree, openmp, tree-traversal

I wrote a simple parallel post order traversal algorithm with OpenMP in C++.

```
#include <string.h>
#include <omp.h>
#define NUM_THREADS 16

struct node {
    node* left;
    node* right;
    int value;
};

void traverseParallelAux(node* cur) {

    if (cur->left != NULL)
        #pragma omp task firstprivate(cur)
        traverseParallelAux(cur->left);

    if (cur->right != NULL)
        #pragma omp task firstprivate(cur)
        traverseParallelAux(cur->right);

    std::string output = std::to_string(cur->value);
    output.append(" ");

    #pragma omp taskwait 
    {
        #pragma omp critical
        {
            std::cout << output;
        }
    }   
}

void traverseParallel(node* cur) {

    #pragma omp parallel num_threads(NUM_THREADS)
    {
        #pragma omp single nowait
        {
            traverseParallelAux(cur);   
        }
    }
}
```

When I run this with a tree with root of value 4 and each other nodes value is by it's level smaller than 4 I get something like this for example (It's not always the same):

1 1 1 2 1 1 2 1 1 1 2 3 2 3 4

The expected result (and the result of the sequential algorithm) is:

1 1 2 1 1 2 3 1 1 2 1 1 2 3 4

This is the code I use to create the tree:

```
void addLeftRight(node* cur, int n) {

    if (n <= 0)
        return;

    node* left = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
    node* right = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));

    left->value = n;
    right->value = n;

    cur->left = left;
    cur->right = right;

    addLeftRight(left, n-1);
    addLeftRight(right, n-1);
}

int main() {
    node* n1 = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
    n1->value = 4;
    addLeftRight(n1, 3);

    traverseParallel(n1);
}
```

Is there a way to adjust the output order so I get the correct result?

As you can see in my code I already tried using a `critical` region and building the string before i print it (as suggested in other questions) but it didn't change anything. Or did I write something wrong?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Can you show the code used to create the initial tree?  Allowing other users to reproduce your problem in a straightforward way would improve the chances of receiving helpful answers.  See [How to create a minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @NicholasM Sure sorry. Updated the question.

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding **why** you'd want the output to match the sequential version. Multi-threaded code can literally do two things at once, so some nodes finish before others depending on random scheduling. If you were to force it to be done in a certain order, you would essentially be making your code sequential (and it would be more complicated and run slower due to the overhead).